# Rotate texture 45 degrees on PlaneGeometry using UV mappings

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to map a rotated texture onto a PlaneGeometry.

Essentially, I have a 44x44 diamond texture that looks like this:

[image: example image]

I would like to map the diamond in the image onto my plane geometry using UVs. Is this possible to do using Three.js? In essence, map texel (0, 22) to uv (0, 0), texel (22, 0) to uv (1.0, 0), and so forth?

Here's the code that I'm using: https://jsfiddle.net/mxLt0bun/2/

```
  geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1);

  texture = loader.load("https://i.imgur.com/DPZiMyK.png")
  texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
  texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;

  material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture
  });
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  // draw edges
  var geo = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(mesh.geometry);
  var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00FF00,
    linewidth: 1
  });
  var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments(geo, mat);
  mesh.add(wireframe);

  scene.add(mesh);
```

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/mxLt0bun/4/

Comment: Yesss. Can you put that in an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify the UVs of your geometry like so:

```
geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1 );

geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ].set( 0.5, 1.0 );
geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 1 ].set( 0.0, 0.5 );
geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 2 ].set( 1.0, 0.5 );
geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ 1 ][ 0 ].set( 0.0, 0.5 );
geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ 1 ][ 1 ].set( 0.5, 0.0 );
geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ].set( 1.0, 0.5 );
```

`BufferGeometry` is more efficient. You might as well use it.

```
geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 1, 1 );

geometry.attributes.uv.setXY( 0, 0.5, 1.0 );
geometry.attributes.uv.setXY( 1, 1.0, 0.5 );
geometry.attributes.uv.setXY( 2, 0.0, 0.5 );
geometry.attributes.uv.setXY( 3, 0.5, 0.0 );
```

three.js r.83